# Jasperreport 6.2 java.lang.StackOverflowError when using subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, tomcat7

When using JasperReport 6.2.0 on a reporting having subreport, I got a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

```
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:886) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:352) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:421) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:396) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2028) 
...
```

Server is openSuse Linux 42.1, Tomcat7.0.53, Java is openjdk version "1.8.0_72", MariaDB database.

Adding `log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.javaflow=info` into `log4j.properties` as I found on some sites did NOT solve the problem.

I also have the commons-javaflow-20060411.jar library in my path.

Testing using JasperReport 6.3.0 raised a

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.suspend()Ljava/lang/Object;

...
```

Issues was NOT present when using Jasperreport 5.x version.

I have exactly the same install on various servers with same libraries versions, java versions, code version, etc... (Linux server, cloned disk installation), but only 3 of 17 servers have the issue...

Same database on refreshed on another server does NOT present the issue... Very strange... Like it's harware related, but it is not since some have same harware and one works and the other not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue using version 6.1.1 of Jasperreports. Solved it on all servers.

http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jasperreports/jasperreports/JasperReports%206.1.1/jasperreports-javaflow-6.1.1.jar
http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jasperreports/jasperreports/JasperReports%206.1.1/jasperreports-fonts-6.1.1.jar
http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jasperreports/jasperreports/JasperReports%206.1.1/jasperreports-6.1.1.jar

**UPDATE:** 
Thanks to @dada67 advise, I upgraded to version 6.3.0 without including the `jasperreports-javaflow-x.y.z.jar` (and removing all 3 files from version 6.1.1) and everything is working fine now.

**So the solution was to remove `jasperreports-javaflow-x.y.z.jar`**

Comment: Note that you do not need both jasperreports-x.y.x.jar and jasperreports-javaflow-x.y.z.jar on the classpath.  The jasperreports-javaflow jar is a variant of the vanilla jar that should only be used when the Javaflow based subreport runner is needed.

Comment: @dada67 : Thank you. I'll try without the javaflow library if it fixes the issue.

Comment: That didn't give you problems in other reports?